# Strange behaviour of MySQL sleep function

Tags: mysql, sleep

I was experimenting with following MySQL queries: (10.1.19-MariaDB)

```
 - select 1 rlike(if(0=sleep(1), 0x28, 0x28)) → NULL
       execution time: 1.0001 seconds
 - select 1 rlike(if(0=0, 0x28, 0x28)) → SQL error as expected: 0x28 = "("
```

Why does MySQL evaluate first expression to NULL? Is optimisation responsible for such unexpected behaviour?
I want to run sleep command first and then compare the result of sleep function (which is zero if sleep function is not interrupted) with 0 ("0=0" → 1 → true) and then let MySQL generate an SQL error. So first do "sleep", then do "SQL error".
Is it possible to achieve this with the MySQL sleep function? (otherwise i would use so called "heavy queries": http://www.sqlinjection.net/heavy-query/)

(Note: No stacked queries here - only subqueries)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using the `SLEEP()` function? It isn't really useful outside of stored procedures.

Comment: I'm testing time based SQL injection where SQL errors are required. So first do something, then sleep X seconds, and then return an SQL error.

Comment: I'm just curious why sleep(X) isn't working as expected. E.g. "select 1 rlike(if(0=BENCHMARK(5000000,MD5('A')),0x28,0x28))" works as expected and requires on my PC ~1.1181 seconds.